# IOS Core Data : Count Duplicated values

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a lot of saved Objects "Tracks" in my app as :

```
@interface Track : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *artistName;
@end
```

How to get the most popular artistName using a NSFetchRequest (and without NSCounterSet)?

Comment: Is it for iOS or OSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it by

- Grouping the results by `artistName`, and
- Creating an `NSExpression` that counts the number of occurrences of `artistName` in those grouped results.

First create the expression, naming it `count`, using the `count` function, and returning an integer result:

```
NSExpression *countExpr = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"count:(artistName)"];
NSExpressionDescription *countExprDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[countExprDesc setName:@"count"];
[countExprDesc setExpression:countExpr];
[countExprDesc setExpressionResultType:NSInteger64AttributeType];
```

Then create the fetch request to use this, both fetching and grouping by the expression value:

```
NSFetchRequest *fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Track"];
[fr setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"artistName", countExprDesc];
[fr setPropertiesToGroupBy:@["artistName"];
[fr setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

When you execute the fetch, you'll get back an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary will have two keys: `artistName` will be values of your `artistName` property, and `count` will be the number of times each artist name appears.

You'll need to find the max value in that array yourself, because unfortunately you can't tell fetch requests to sort results by expression values.